# SIFT and SURF Implementation Libraries

Tags: matlab, image-processing, sift, surf

In my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550896/sift-and-surf-feature-extraction-implementation-using-matlab) I asked about SIFT and SURF implementation in MATLAB source codes and several links were received. Thanks for all. Now, I have another question. These SIFT implementations are like libraries that we are using (for an example when coding c++ programming, we are including iostream library. But we don't have to change any code which is inside that library) right?. So, I can just use these SIFT implementations as a library and do not need to change any code for my images right? That means sift implementation is working for any image? Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VLFeat](http://www.vlfeat.org) is a C library, that you can use from C++ (without changing the library). The images have to be stored as one `float` per pixel. You can read the C API documentation here: http://vlfeat.org/api/sift_8h.html

Answer (score 2):

You can also checkout [Rob Hess's SIFT implementation](http://blogs.oregonstate.edu/hess/code/sift/). The implementation is done step by step as mentioned in David Lowe's SIFT paper. Quite useful for those who want to understand SIFT.

Both VLFeat & Hess's are [award winning](http://www.acmmm10.org/2010/10/open-source-software-competition-winners/) software.

Utkarsh Sinha has created a nice [tutorial](http://www.aishack.in/2010/05/sift-scale-invariant-feature-transform/) on SIFT.

Comment: I'm just trying to make Rob Hess's implementation work with C++ for the last two days and am getting massive linkage problems... I was wondering, did you ever manage to use the RH implementation with C++, or only with C?